# Why everytime page react re-renders checkbox within map gets checked by default?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a table that gets populated by an ticketArray array of objects brought from an api.
Every object gets a final column of type checkbox
Every time I click on the checkbox I add that object ID to a "toDeleteRow" array.
And only when the Button Delete is clicked I loop through ticketArray comparing every item id against ids in toDeleteRow. If ids are equal I delete that object from ticketArray and I wipe out toDeleteRow
**The problem is when the page gets re-render the first of the remaining rows gets checked by default (and internally gets added to the toDeleteRow WHICH I don't want to)**

```
<tbody>
    {ticketArray.map((ticket: any, index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
            <td>{ticket.Id}</td>
            <td>{ticket.createdDate}</td>
            <td>PR</td>
            <td>
                <i className="icon-edit icon-large" title="Edit" onClick={handlePopupModifShow} />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input onChange={() => { AddToRemove(ticket.Id) }}
                    className="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
    ))}
</tbody>
```

This are my functions:

```
const AddToRemove= (id: string) => {
    if (toDeleteRow.includes(id)) {
        let val = toDeleteRow.indexOf(id, 0)
        if (val> -1) { toDeleteRow.splice(val, 1); }
    }
    else { toDeleteRow.push(id) }
}

const Remove = () => {

    if (toDeleteRow.length > 0) {
        let newArray: SetStateAction<{ Id: string; createDate: string }[]> = []
        for (let x = 0; x < toDeleteRow.length; x++) {
            newArray = ticketArray.filter(function (obj) {
                return obj.Id !== toDeleteRow[x];
            });
        }
        setTicketArray(newArray)
        toDeleteRow.splice(0, toDeleteRow.length)
    }
    else {
        alert("Select at least one row")
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? It's driving me nuts :S

Comment: Your checkbox-component is not a controlled component, meaning it is not controlled by react state. That would make it easier to control if its checked or not.
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: It might be because you are using the `index` as a key since the order of the items is changing. https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318